# scala Liftweb - retrieving content of tag

Tags: javascript, html, scala, lift

Im new to lift, so the problem is:
I have a div and a textarea in it. I also have a button, and I want to get    #code textarea content without refreshing page (actually, it isn't important)
I tried googling a lot, but there is no answers for 4 pages :C
Pls, help!
`<div lift="Snippet.button">
        <textarea id="code">
            xdxdxdxdxd xhere goes the code
        </textarea>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-default"   id="but">
            Submit
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden">
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of parsing myself a lot of sites, i found something :

`JE.ValById("#code")` - returns value of textarea or any input

`JsCmds.SetValById("#code", "test value")` 
- sets vlaue to found element

Comment: Worth noting: all of this is generating JavaScript on the client. So another answer can be to write JS on the client and communicate with it by invoking functions or by dispatching events. See the approach described [in this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/liftweb/0zw5P-aMWoo/gEZmftl6F34J)—it can work for comet or AJAX communication.